# Handle webview response in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I have theoretical question, is there a possibility to access server response or source in ios webview?

For example, we have html form loaded in webview. After sending form inside of webview I need to parse response to read some data.

Comment: Typically in HTML, when a form is submitted by the user the server replies in the form of HTML which is displayed as a new web page; this will happen automatically.

Comment: I know but I need to pare resposne to know what kind of data I have there. Sometimes it might be html code (when error occurs) but it can be also json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to handle the `NSRequest/NSHTTPResponse` calls yourself, to get the data to decide what to do - then you can decide if you want to send said data to a web view, or render JSON or whatever.

Comment: So in ios there is no such thing as reading webview html (or other data) source?

Comment: There may be - but I believe you'll be happier with having the control and determining what to pass to the web view as opposed to trying to get it to tell you things via delegation with content it may or may not understand how to render. By all means though try if you think that's a better fit.